# $.post returns syntax error, unexpected '\'

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Okay, so i'm writing some code to post something to PHP script and get back data.
However, when i do so i get an "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /home/multipla/public_html/private/data2.php on line 32" error.

I've tried different things to remove this, either changing the posting code or changing small things in the PHP script. (I do not remember them all)

This is my post function:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "data2.php",
      data: { id: "1", name: "9903286" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {alert("Data: " + msg);
});
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$PORT = 4321;
$HOST = "THE IP (Removed cause ddos)";

$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
or die("error: could not create socket\n");

$succ = socket_connect($sock, $HOST, $PORT)
or die("error: could not connect to host\n");
$text = "BUY:".$id.":".$name;

socket_write($sock, $text."\n", strlen($text."\n") + 1) or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");

$reply = socket_read($sock, 10000) or die("error: failed to read from socket\n");

echo $reply;
```

?>

The PHP script works fine if i run it alone and put 1 and 9903286 instead of $id and $name.
Also, line 32 is the "socket_write" line in the PHP script.

Comment: It is having an issue with backslashes for some reason. try removing all `\n`'s from that line or possibly the occurrence before line #32.

Comment: Is this the whole script? Because I'm counting around 20 lines, where would line 32 be exactly?

Comment: Sorry, removed my comments cause i didn't want it to be longer than necessery.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I can't remove the \n:s, cause the server is reading lines and without those it would get stuck in a loop.

Comment: Can you do `echo '<textarea>'.$text.'</textarea>';` to see if the data isn't screwing things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try POSTing to your script with a tool like this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/htt/

What you need to do is see the raw data and headers you get back. There are also plugins for firefox and chrome for doing this.

Try this to replace your current connect/POST method:

```
$connectionString = 'http://92.68.123.45';
$paramList = array(
  'name' => 'Bob'
  'phone' => 8161234567
);
$varString = http_build_query($paramList);

$opts = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => "POST",
    'content' => $varString
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts));
$result = file_get_contents($connectionString, false, $context);
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without third party tools? Even using jquery were hard for me.

Comment: The only reason I suggest 3rd party tools is so that you eliminate jquery from it and just see the raw information. You might be getting an error in the headers and just can't see it because jquery doesn't report that info.

Comment: You might also have better luck with some PHP libraries for the server-side of this. Zend framework has a lot of classes that can be used outside the framework. Also, why are you not just posting directly from javascript? It might simplify it. Can the server your PHP script sits on actually ping the other server?

Comment: You might want to SSH to the server that this script resides on and then try using cURL to post to the destination server. Also look into using PHP's cURL functions or file_get_contents (for which you can create a context stream in which you can post data to something).

Comment: What do you mean by "ping the other server"? If you mean that it can connect to it, yes, i can get the data when only using the data2.php file.

Comment: I just updated my post with a suggestion. Try that for sending your message to the other server.

Comment: The other server is a .jar file running a server on TCP port 4321 in my computer. Where does it use the port?

Comment: EDIT: Fixed an error, but now that i use that code, nothing happens.